# Intuitive explanation for a map $z \to z^p$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $p$ be prime and let $G$ be the group of $p$-power roots of 1 in $\mathbb{C}$ . Prove the map $z \to z^p$ is a surjective homomorphism.

$\textbf{My Attempt:}$

$G=\{ z \in \mathbb{C} \mid z^{p^n}=1\}$

Let $\phi: G \to G$ defines such that $\phi(z)=z^p$.

I need an intuitive explanation of what exactly such a map, $\phi$, is doing.

Comment: Surjective onto what, $G$? That isn't defined in the problem.

Comment: @Ian. I copied the question directly out of Dummit and Foote, this is all that is given. Your question is exactly where I am confused as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\phi$ is a homomorphism: $\phi(a)\phi(b)=a^p b^p=(ab)^p=\phi(ab)$.

$\phi$ maps into $G$: if $a \in G$, then for some $n \ge 0$, $a^{p^n} =1$. If $n=0$, then $\phi(1)=1 \in G$. Otherwise, since $(a^p)^{p^{n-1}}=1$, we have $\phi(a)=a^p  \in G$ if $n \ge 1$.

$\phi$ is surjective onto $G$ (?): if $a\in G$, then for some $n \ge 0$, $a^{p^n}=1$. An element in the preimage of $a$ would be any $p$th root of $a$ (i.e., any root of the polynomial $x^p-a$). Such an element, call it $b$, would be in $G$ because $b^{p^{n+1}}=a^{p^n}=1$.