# Extension of map $z\mapsto z^p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-homomorphism, roots-of-unity

Let $p$ be a prime and $G$ be the group of p-power roots of 1 in $\mathbb{C}$. Prove that $z\mapsto z^p$ is a surjective homomorphism and deduce that $G$ is isomorphic to a proper quotient of itself.

I have done the first part of the proof, and in fact it is here: [Intuitive explanation for a map $z \to z^p$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/861458/intuitive-explanation-for-a-map-z-to-zp) What I am having trouble with is the "deduce..." part. I'm not sure what is meant by "a proper quotient of itself," and I don't know where the isomorphism will come from since we only have a surjective homomorphism. Am I supposed to show that the function from the proof is also one-to-one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any surjective group homomorphism $f : G\to H$ induces an isomorphism $G/\ker(f)\to H$ (this is simply the [first isomorphism theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems#First_isomorphism_theorem)). Thus, your surjective map
\begin{align*}
G&\to G\\
z&\mapsto z^p
\end{align*}
induces an isomorphism $G/\ker(z\mapsto z^p)\cong G$.

The above answers where the isomorphism comes from, let's cover what it means by "proper quotient." A proper quotient of a group $G$ is a quotient by a normal nontrivial subgroup $N.$ That is, the quotient map $\pi : G\to G/N$ is surjective (as always) but not injective. So, what you need to show is not that $z\mapsto z^p$ is one-to-one, but rather that it is *not* one-to-one! This is equivalent to $\ker(z\mapsto z^p)$ being a nontrivial subgroup of $G,$ and this isn't too hard to show - you don't need to determine the kernel entirely, you only need to exhibit one nontrivial element contained in it!